# Printing text file in java?This document does not conform to the Adobe Document Structuring Conventions and may not print correctly

Tags: java, printing, rhel, cups

I have written the below code in java for printing a simple text file,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
public class PrintImage {
  static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
      PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
      pras.add(new Copies(1));
/*      PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_US_ASCII.AUTOSENSE, pras);
      if (pss.length == 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available.");*/
      PrintService ps =  PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
      System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
      DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
      Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_US_ASCII.AUTOSENSE, null);
      job.print(doc, pras);
      fin.close();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
System.out.println(ie.toString());
    } catch (PrintException pe) {
System.out.println(pe.toString());
      pe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Server 6.0 with JDK1.6.0_43 as a development platform.The code was executed without errors.And also i have verified in CUPS that the job is queued in printer queue.But printer is not printing the job.I got the following error in CUPS log,

> W [18/Apr/2013:15:09:24 +0530] [Job 15] This document does not conform
>   to the Adobe Document Structuring Conventions and may not print
>   correctly!

But The same program works well only for pdf files under RHEL6.0.Only txt,doc files are not printing.

One more thing is the same code is working perfectly under Ubuntu 12.04 and RHEL4.7. But with RHEL6.0 only pdf file is printing.

Please help me to get the problem solved...